# How to make an instance itself removed from an array using for ...of?

Tags: oop, ecmascript-6, iterator

Now i have an array "enermies" including several instances of class Enermy, i want to make an iterator that if an enermy is killed, it will be removed from array.
I know how to write in traditional JS

```
for(let i= enermies.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(enermies[i].iskilled){
       enermies.splice(i,1)
  }
}
```

but as to ES6, is there a better way using "for...of"?

```
for (enermy of enermies){
    if(enermy.iskilled){
        ??????
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that `enermies.slice(i,1)` doesn't actually remove anything. Did you mean to use `splice`?

Comment: yes, it should be `splice`,now I have corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because `slice` is not a mutative function, so it does nothing. Even if you use the correct `splice`, deleting elements inside loop is dangerous and you need to avoid it. Instead, one of the simplest ways is `filter`:

```
 enemies = enemies.filter(enemy => !enemy.iskilled);
```

If you're dealing with only one element, you can also do this:

```js
const index = enemies.findIndex(enemy => enemy.iskilled);
if (index >= 0) enemies.splice(index, 1):
```

This way you keep the array in place and don't have to re-assign a new array, though you'll need to do a proper loop if you want to delete more than one elements.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer help me a lot.